# Liferay document library auto generate file of size 51MB named FAB-38-49.Lucifier22

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Liferay 6.2 GA3 running on Linux platform with Mysql as DB auto generating some files (named FAB-25-37.Lucifier22 as a rar file format). At any situations does liferay auto generate file like this?
The file nale FAB-25-37 is changing on files like FAB-38-47

Comment: Where are those file generated? What they contain?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Liferay itself does not generate those! They may be generated/needed by

- custom Liferay modules / extensions / customizations
- backup tools
- log rotation and archiving tools
- monitoring tools
- ...